# How to alert a panel that it's visible when switch panels in a CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

I have two ***JPanel*** in the ***CardLayout*** of a ***JPanel*** inside my **ProgramFrame** (*extends* ***JFrame***), they are **ChooserPanel** and **ShowPanel**.

In **ChooserPanel**, I choose a number to appear at the **ShowPanel** and click a ***Button*** to change the ***Panel*** in **ProgramFrame**, switching from **ChooserPanel** to **ShowPanel**. But how can I, elegantly, notify the ***Button*** click to **ProgramFrame**, so it can switch the ***JPanel***, and communicate the number chosen to **ShowPanel**?

I put a *listener* in the ***ChooserPanel*** to notify the button click to **ProgramFrame**. If it is the best way, so I just need to know how to communicate the number chosen to **ShowPanel**.

I thought about doing the following:

```
public class ProgramFrame extends JFrame implements SwitchThePanelListener {

    private JPanel cardPanel;

    public ProgramFrame() {
        this.cardPanel = new JPanel();

        ChooserPanel chooser = new ChooserPanel(this); // passing the listener
        ShowPanel show = new ShowPanel();

        cardPanel.add(chooser, "chooser");
        cardPanel.add(show, "show");

        CardLayout layout = (CardLayout) cardPanel.getLayout();
        layout.show(cardPanel, "chooser");

        /** Code to set and show the layout **/
    }

    public void switchThePanelListener() {
        CardLayout layout = (CardLayout) cardPanel.getLayout();
        layout.show(cardPanel, "chooser");
    }

}
```

The code of the *listener*:

```
public interface SwitchThePanelListener {
    public void switchThePanelListener();
}
```

The **ChooserPanel**:

```
public class ChooserPanel extends JPanel {

    public ChooserPanel(SwitchThePanelListener listener) {
        /** Code to set the layout and button to fire the listener **/
    }

}
```

And the **ShowPanel**:

```
public class ChooserPanel extends JPanel {

    public ChooserPanel() {
        /** Code to set the layout to show the number (how?) **/
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have view and you have controller. Now you require model. In JGoodies lib you can find a good interface: ValueModel. It looks like

```
public interface ValueModel {
   Object getValue();
   void setValue(Object o);
   void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener pl);
   void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener pl);
}
```

Your controller instantiate a ValueModel (standard implementation in JGoodies is ValueHolder) and transfers (sets) to both of panels. ChooserPanel sets the value into the model after a button click and ShowPanel register a listener to get notification about value change. Use the same way if you have more than one property to transfer between panels (simply combine all these values in one object which will be set into ValueModel) or for the bidirectional communication.